# How does one qualitatively describe the cubic increase of experimental data

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I have generated some data Y and would like to describe its variation as a function of some variable X. Using MS Excel, I obtained the trendline shown in the figure below which suggests that Y varies approximately cubically with X. However, I would like to omit the trendline itself (leaving only the data points marked by the blue diamonds) and describe the data qualitatively in an increasing sense. To that end, would it be accurate for me to use the following statement: the data Y increases approximately cubically with X?

[image]

Comment: Insofar as what you really mean to say is "I found a cubic polynomial whose values at the $X$ points agree fairly well with the data". I would also suggest  a rescaling of the data, as the coefficients of your polynomial are quite small.

Comment: By the way, y *de*creases if x *in*creases.

Comment: There are high risks in trying to extrapolate a polynomial curve

Comment: callculus I should have stated in my original post that the variable X represents a physical quantity whose magnitude increases in the negative direction.